# Unable to load base64 image in ionic 2 from external source

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am trying to load a base64 image in Ionic 2 from an external server.  I have tried configuring the CSP as below:

```
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="
    default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';
    img-src 'self' data: blob: ;
    " />
```

However, the error still remains as:

```
because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self' data: blob: ".
```

The image tag is at `<img [src]="base64Image" class="editor-img" no-padding/>`, with base64Image being a variable in the page itself.

Help?

Comment: Show how you are retrieving the image. Short Pnkr is always best for quick help. They also sometime help you identify the problem by way of isolation.

Comment: The image endpoint is retrieving all right, have printed the endpoint and it works.  Updating to show the image tag.

Comment: Can you show `base64Image` value ? You can truncate the thing if it is large - I am only interested in first 100 characters.

Comment: For example try https://plnkr.co/edit/VZFAZos0HBr69D3GkE5Z?p=preview

Comment: The CSPs did not matter but it is a plnkr.